# Adding arrow to contours in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following MWE that draws contours at a particular level:

```
x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);
y = linspace(0,4*pi);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = sin(X)+cos(Y);

figure
contour(X,Y,Z, [ 1 1])
colorbar
```

This works quite well, however, is there a function/handle that can be used to draw an arrow along the contour to display the direction? Or do I have to do it manually?

---

EDIT I'm looking for something like this that will work on whatever color the background has. So a white arrowhead with black/dark border.

[image]

---

Code so far

```
theta = 80*pi/180;
r = 0.1;
x = 0.4; y = 0.6;
u = r * cos(theta);
v = r * sin(theta);
quiver(x,y,u,v);
```

Comment: Contours don't have an inherent direction, so you'll have to determine what that direction is yourself and likely write something custom to do it for you.

Comment: @Suever Thanks, do you have a suggestion for what I should look in to?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Maybe provide an example illustration?

Comment: @Suever Hope it is clear now, let me know if I should expand on it

Comment: It's still not clear how you plan on determining the direction. `contour` could trace each of those either clockwise or counter-clockwise.

Comment: @Suever The direction I can determine manually, e.g. by making a quiver plot. Knowing the direction, I can draw the arrow head manually

Comment: Ok so what part of that are you unsure of?

Comment: @Suever I'm wondering what the best way to draw the arrowhead is. Here is what I could come up with, but somewhat cumbersome to fine-tune it such that the angle is correct wrt. the contour, `annotation('arrow', 'Linestyle', 'None', 'HeadWidth', 12, 'HeadStyle', 'vback3', 'X', [0.5 0.5], 'Y', [0.5 0.5]);`

Comment: What's wrong with `quiver`?

Comment: @Suever I tried `quiver`, but I can't find the parameter to tweak the arrowhead size nor remove the "body" of the arrow. I posted my example in the OP.